# Execute a method when image is loaded

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I've been trying to execute a method when a image has fully loaded, but it simply throws an error that my function doesn't exists:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: imageLoaded is not defined
> at HTMLImageElement.onload (projetos:1)

Here's my code:

```js
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <h2>{{projeto.nome}}</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1" id="img-container">
        <img :src="projeto.foto" :alt="projeto.nome" onload="imageLoaded()">
        <div class="row" id="info">
          <div class="col-xs-6">Conclusão: {{projeto.duracao}}</div>
          <div class="col-xs-6">Projeto realizado em {{projeto.ano}}</div>
          <br><br>
          <p>{{projeto.descricao}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import { eventBus } from "../../main";

export default {
  props: ["projeto"],
  methods: {
    imageLoaded() { // the function i want to execute
      eventBus.loading(false);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I've tried using `:load=""` (which I discovered that doesn't exists) and placing a function outside my export default scope. Since my images are in a `v-for` I think `onload` is the best way of achieving this.

So is there a better way? How can I do this? Is there a directive I can use? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `v-on` directive or the shorthand `@` for listening for DOM events like you would do for example with `@click=""` - so `@load="imageLoaded()"` should work.